# Cyclic api calls in microservices

Tags: rest, web-services, microservices, loose-coupling

Assume there are two services,

1. Product Service
2. Coupon service

Coupon is tagged against the product. And when the coupon is changed for any product there is an API call from product service to the coupon service which calculates the coupon discount and sends back to the product service. And product service maintains that cache. However, To calculate the discount, coupon service need the product information such as product category, SKU type etc. and discount varies based on that so there is again an API call to the product service making it cyclic call. There are a couple of solutions,

1. maintain product cache at the coupon service. - This is an overhead as we need to maintain the cache on every product field update and this is not the solution we are looking for.
2. When product service makes an API call to the coupon service, send all the fields it needs - There is tight coupling in this approach.

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: In those cases I do not split into different Microservices. 
Having it within the same service you will gain performance and skip the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have decided that you need 2 different services for this, I would agree that a cyclical dependency is kind of bad and worth trying to remove.

However, I don't really see it being needed here. I think the "coupon" service needs to be aware of the "product" service, but not vice versa.

The issue you are having though is that your coupon service needs to respond to a change that's happening on the product service. Right now you solved this by having the product service send a message to the coupon service.

Some possibilities to fix this include:

1. Have the coupon service occasionally poll for updates.
2. Deploy a pub-sub system. Make a 'product change' something you can subscribe to and have the coupon subscribe to that.

I would suggest a third option though. It sounds to me that a 'coupon change' as a concept should not at all exist in the product service. Why does it? It sounds like you actually might have 3 different services:

1. Product information
2. Coupon information
3. Cart